# Problems when Installing PyQt4 on Mac OSX 10.9: Error: Failed to determine the detail of your Qt installation

Tags: python, macos, qt

Problems when Installing PyQt4 on Mac OSX 10.9：Error: Failed to determine the detail of your Qt installation.

I have installed  Qt 5.2.1 for Mac (378 MB) successfuly，the directory is

> /Users/Bravelee/Qt5.2.1/

I followed this steps to install PyQt4：

1. install and Make sip （sip-4.15.3 ），successfuly
2. install and Make PyQt4；（found Error）

> wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.10.3/PyQt-mac-gpl-4.10.3.tar.gz
>
> tar -xzvf PyQt-mac-gpl-4.10.3.tar.gz
>
> cd PyQt-mac-gpl-4.10.3
>
> python configure-ng.py -q /Users/Bravelee/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/clang_64/bin/qmake -d /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ --sip /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/sip

Error as following：

> BraveleedeMacBook-Pro:PyQt-mac-gpl-4.10.3 Bravelee$ python configure-ng.py -q /Users/Bravelee/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/clang_64/bin/qmake -d /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ --sip /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/sip
>
> Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
>
> Determining the details of your Qt installation...
>
> Error: Failed to determine the detail of your Qt installation. Try again using
> the --verbose flag to see more detail about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

PyQt4 requires Qt 4 and will not work with Qt 5.2. Either use Qt 5.2 + PyQt5 (recommended) or Qt 4.8 + PyQt4.